# Is there any backport-util for fork join framework for Java 1.5?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, fork-join

when concurrency utils were introduced there was backport-util. For Java 1.6 there is an implementation for fork/join framework http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/djg/teachingMaterials/grossmanSPAC_forkJoinFramework.html

Is there any alternative for Java 1.5?

Comment: I was under the impression `fork()` was intentionally omitted from the Java API, which makes me question the integrity of making an external library to do that.

Comment: Have you tried it on 1.5? If so, works/doesn't work? I've used jsr166y on 1.6 and AFAIK it should run on 1.5 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not expect any back ports of new functionality in JDK 7 to 1.5 since that's two major versions back.  Is there a reason you can't upgrade to JDK 1.6?

Comment: just curious to know how it can be back-ported as it has been done with concurrency utils

Answer (score 0):

On this page http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/ you can find all the packages related to the JSR-166 (java.util.concurrent). There are also backported packages for the JDK6, support for 1.5 doesn't seem to be available.